# xcode debugger gives bad access when reading vars in protocol extension

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift2

I noticed this problem in a real project and then reproduced it in this simple app that just has a view controller with a tableView that does nothing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}

protocol Proto : class {
    weak var tableView : UITableView! { get }
}

extension Proto {
    func omg () {
        print("tableView : \(self.tableView)")
    }
}

class ViewControllerExtended : ViewController, Proto {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        omg()
    }
}
```

If you run this, the app will run fine and you will see something along the lines of

```
tableView : <UITableView: 0x7fc5b702ea00; frame = (144 148; 240 128); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc5b5e0be60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc5b5d0f800>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {240, 0}>
```

in the console.  However, if you add a breakpoint on the print line, and in the debugger you try to print the value of the tableview, you will get a bad access error

[image: debugger issue]

Not having full use of the debugger isn't the end of the world but I do want to implement a substantial amount of logic in a protocol extension so not having it isn't ideal.